# Spring Integration + Swagger

Tags: spring, spring-integration, dsl, spring-integration-dsl, spring-dsl

I am trying to integrate swagger in Spring Integration flow. I know there is no support for Spring integration by swagger, but I am trying to do it manually. So, my approach is like, scan the endpoints from Integration flow along with the headers and append it in the swagger. But for the I couldn't fetch the endpoints from integration flow. I am using Spring integration DSL in which I cannot find the EndpointScanner Interface and any other concrete interfaces in dsl.
Please help to find a solution.

```
public class MyEndpointScanner implements EndpointScanner {

    @Override
    public List<Endpoint> scanEndpoints(IntegrationFlow integrationFlow) {
        List<Endpoint> endpoints = new ArrayList<>();

        for (FlowStep flowStep : integrationFlow.getSteps()) {
            if (flowStep instanceof Endpoint) {
                endpoints.add((Endpoint) flowStep);
            }
        }

        List<Endpoint> filteredEndpoints = endpoints.stream()
                .filter(endpoint -> endpoint.getUrl().startsWith("/channels"))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        return filteredEndpoints;
    }
}
```

But the `EndpointScanner` is not available in Spring integration DSL.

Comment: What you show has nothing to do with Spring. Apparently that `IntegrationFlow` is indeed not an `org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlow`. Please, modify your tags for the question for respective API you use. Sorry, not familiar with Swagger at all to help further.